# Catch change event of gwt InputElement

Tags: java, gwt, jquery-mobile, input

Programming on gwt, there should be possibility to attach a change event to an input element, that is at Java like this:

```
@UiField
InputElement mWorkCompleted;
```

and in `.gwt.xml`-file:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="workCompleted" ui:field="mWorkCompleted"
                class="custom" />
```

**Edit 1:**

Some more challenges came when I read the rest of the code: this is rendered to screen with jQuery and that's why the `InputElement` is used. Part of Java file:

```
@Override
public void setWorkCompleted(boolean completed) {
    mWorkCompleted.setChecked(completed);
    JQuery.create(mWorkCompleted).checkboxradio(JQuery.REFRESH);
}
```

How to achieve that simple looking thing? jQuery version 1.8.1

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I have a gwt mobile app, where at someFile.java is that inputElement and someFile.gwt.xml has the counter part like given. Somehow, when you put a tick to the UI, it should trigger some event that I can catch. InputElement itself does not have such. InputElement is at packet: com.google.gwt.dom.client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give dom element event with  [Event Api](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html).

```
Event.sinkEvents(mWorkCompleted, Event.ONCHANGE);
        Event.setEventListener(mWorkCompleted, new EventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer your `UiField` with its concrete type? as far as I know it needs to be `CheckBox` type in above code. Then you can use following recommended way of binding event handlers to uibinder inputs.

```
@UiHandler("mWorkCompleted")
void handleCheck(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> evt)
{
    System.err.println("evt value "+evt.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible, I use jQuery also. See edit1. Sorry, I missed that essential part from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this Element via your defined panel or widgets like

```
yourWidget.add(new HTML("<input type = 'checkbox'/>"))
```

And add your handler for your widget. (prefer DOMHandler ). And then check it's value like

```
            public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
            EventTarget eventTarget = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
            Node node = Node.as(eventTarget);

            if (Element.is(node)) {
            if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(elem.getAttribute("checked"))) {
                elem.setAttribute("checked", "on");
                    // Do something
                }
            else if ("on".equalsIgnoreCase(elem.getAttribute("checked"))) {
                elem.removeAttribute("checked");
                    // Do something
                }
        }
```